# What is the probability of forming a cluster of the size M given N random points?

Tags: probability, clustering

Suppose we generate a sample of uniformly distributed numbers of the size $N$ in the range $[0, 1]$: $x \sim U[0, 1]$. We consider that if the difference between any 2 numbers is smaller than some value $\varepsilon << 1$, they are connected together and form a "cluster". Then, if any other number appears to be closer that $\varepsilon$ to any member of an existing cluster, it joins that cluster.

The question is, given the sample size $N$, what is the probability that at least one cluster of size $\geq m$ will be formed?

I can see that the probability of forming the cluster of the size 2 is $p = 2 \varepsilon N$, but I'm not sure where to go next, since we have to take into account the number and distances between the numbers that are already in the cluster.

Can anyone give me a hint? :)

Comment: +1.  But when  $2x_mN \gt 1$ that cannot be a probability, indicating what you "see" is  wrong.  *Why* it is wrong might provide some insight into the problem.  BTW, might I suggest changing the notation?  People will want to index your numbers as $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N,$ but that would give two different meanings to "$x_m.$"  A distinctly different type of symbol, such as $\varepsilon,$ would be better as a name for the linkage threshold.

Comment: @whuber What you suggest makes sense, I've updated the question. And yes, apparently my equation for $m=2$ special case is not correct, thanks for noticing!

Comment: May I ask if this problem is purely of theoretical interest or if it is driven by some application?

Comment: @papgeo just doing some modeling for self-education. I was initially interested in 2D case, i.e. the probability of forming clusters on a plane, but then realized that even in 1D it's not trivial for me.